# Capybara with rspec doesn't always find button (test faills)

Tags: rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6

I am fighting with rspec and one button. In my html.erb i have

```
<button name="Collapse bank accounts" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-circle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#of-bank-ucties" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="of-bank-ucties">
     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Which generates button with svg from fontawesome.

In my rspec i have

```
button_to_expand_bu = find_button('Collapse bank accounts')
button_to_expand_bu.click

expect(page).to have_selector(:css, '[data-bs-toggle="collapse"][data-bs-target="#of-bank-ucties"][aria-expanded="true"]')
```

The thing is the test fails in 50 % of the runs and i can't figure out why is it so unreliable.

I have tried to find the button with find(path), click_button(button), find().click, but every each of them has the same result. Sometimes it passes, sometimes it doesn't ...

What is going on here really ?

I am using the latest gems of everyting and the button is visible, i see him in screenshots, there is no way it can be invisible. When tests are going in chromium i see the test stop when it should click on button, waits for 1 second and shows it failed ...

Comment: What is the exact error you get, and which line of your test is the error coming from?

Comment: unable to find element with given css, error line is expect(page)...

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is coming from your `expect(page)...` line it means Capybara believes it has clicked the button (otherwise the error would come from the `find_button` or `click` lines. That means there are only a couple of reasons for your issue

1. The CSS you're checking for isn't correct
   This is probably not the case since you claim it works 50% of the time
2. The click is occurring but you're not giving it enough time for the CSS to change
   Test that by increasing the maximum time `have_selector` will wait - `expect(page).to have_selector(:css, '[data-bs-toggle="collapse"][data-bs-target="#of-bank-ucties"][aria-expanded="true"]', wait: 10)`
3. The click is occuring but the page isn't ready for the click.  Test that by adding a `sleep 3` before the `click` call - If that solves the issue then you need to find something to expect for before clicking the button which indicates the page is ready
4. You're animating the button onto the page and the button is moving while Capybara is attempting to click it.  Test that the same way as #3 (sleeping to give time for the animation to finish) and if it fixes the issue you need to set an expectation that would indicate the animation is complete, or disable animation when testing.

Note:  `click_button` is defined as `find_button(...).click` - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/f7ab0b5cd5da86185816c2d5c30d58145fe654ed/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L57 - so there is zero advantage to doing it as two separate calls unless you need access to the button element (`button_to_expand_bu`) later in your code.